# Canvas adapter / Tableau dashboard

Tags: visualforce, canvas

Using the canvas adapter for SFDC, I am trying to embed a Tableau Dashbaord into the account page. Below is the code i am using.

The problem is that it is not properly passing the parameter.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:canvasApp applicationName="Tableau_for_Salesforce"
    height="600px"
    width="700px"
    parameters="
    {
        'ts.javascriptLib': 'https://tableau.cape-link.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js',
        'ts.height': '600',
        'ts.width': '700',
        'ts.hostUrl': 'https://tableau.cape-link.com/',
        'ts.siteRoot': '/t/R1_Reporting',
        'ts.name': 'SalesforceDashboard/Dashboard1',
        'ts.tabs': 'yes',
        'ts.toolbar': 'yes',
        'ts.trustedTicket.host': 'tableau.cape-link.com',
        'ts.filter':'xxID={!xxx_ID__c}'
    }"/>
</apex:page>
```

'xxID' is the Tableau field and xxx_ID__c is the custom field from SF.

I get the following error.

> Error: Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.RouteOne_ID__c'

Comment: This is the error Error: Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.xxx_ID__c'

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a field's value by referencing as `{!xxx_ID__c}`. This [syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm) is used to access a method from the controller associated with the VF page. In your scenario you have a standard controller and thus the error is complaining that there does not exist a property with that name.

If you want to get the value of this field from the record, you will need to use:

```
{!account.xxx_ID__c}
```

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_access_data.htm):

> For example, a page that uses the Account standard controller can use {!account.name} to return the value of the name field on the account that is currently in context.